# Keep wallpapers specific to individual PC under the same Microsoft account in 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, display-settings, microsoft-account

I have several Windows 8.1 machines, but finally set up my first with dual monitors. I log in with my Microsoft account on them all to maintain the experience between them all. However, I added a dual-monitor background to this machine, and it looks very bad on the single monitor machines.

Is there a way to specify that the background is for "only this machine"?

Comment: Disable syncing between the machines.

Comment: Wouldn't that then keep ALL settings from syncing?

Comment: You can choose for the most part what is synced.  It might be all or nothing.though, if it is, then that's your answer ;$

Comment: You could put `Background.jpg` into `%windir%\Web\Wallpaper\Windows` and make this a copy of whichever image is best for each machine. You can then set the background to this file from "Windows Desktop Backgrounds`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to PC settings, underneath "OneDrive" there is a section called "Sync settings". Inside of there, you can select what settings get synced between devices.

- Personalization settings

  - Start screen
  - Appearance
  - Desktop personalization *** This is the one to keep a background to only this device
- App settings

  - Apps that have been installed
  - App data
  - Other settings
  - Web Browser
  - Passwords
  - Language preferences
  - Ease of Access
  - Other Windows settings (File explorer, mouse, etc)
  - Back up settings

Comment: I would have looked but I didn't have a machine connected to a Mocrosoft Acccout handy

Comment: Not a problem. I appreciate the pointer in the correct direction. This was one of those situations where the keywords I was using in my googles wasn't hitting the correct searches.